# Tfs custom work item value migration

Tags: tfs

I have a task to create reports about various work items from a Team Foundation Server 2010 instance. They are looking for more information than the query tools seem to expose which is why I am not using the OOB reporting capabilities. The documentation on [creating custom reports against TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730837.aspx) identify the Tfs_Analysis cube and the Tfs_Warehouse database as the intended sources for reporting.

They have created a [custom work item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243889.aspx), "Deployment Requests", to track requests for code migrations. This work item has custom urgency levels (critical, medium, low).

According to [Manually Process the Data Warehouse and Analysis Services Cube for Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400237.aspx), every two minutes my ODS (Tfs_DefaultCollection) should sync with the Tfs_Warehouse and every 2 hours it hits the Tfs_Analysis cube. The basic work items correctly show up in my Tfs_Warehouse except not all of the data makes it over, in particular, the urgency isn't getting migrated.

As a concrete example, work item 19301 was a deployment request. This is what they can see  using the native query tool from the web front-end.
[image: tfs work item query]

I can find it in the Tfs_DefaultCollection and the "Urgency" is mapped to Fld10176.

```
SELECT 
    Fld10176 AS Urgency
, * 
FROM Tfs_DefaultCollection.dbo.WorkItemsAre 
WHERE ID = 19301
```

trimmed results...

```
Urgency                       Not A Field   Changed Date 
1 - Critical - (Right Away)   58            2011-09-07 15:52:29.613
```

If I query the warehouse, I see the deployment request and the "standard" data (people, time, area, etc)

```
SELECT
    DWI.System_WorkItemType
,   DWI.Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Priority
,   DWI.Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Severity
,   *
FROM
    Tfw_Warehouse.dbo.DimWorkItem DWI
WHERE
    DWI.System_Id = 19301
```

Trimmed results

```
System_WorkItemType   Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Priority   Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Severity
Deployment Request    NULL                             NULL
```

I am not the TFS admin (first exposure to TFS is at this new gig) and thus far, they've been rather ...unhelpful.

- Is there be a way to map that custom field over to an existing field in the Tfs_Warehouse? (Backfilling legacy values would be great but fixing current/future is all I need)
- Is there a different approach I should be using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mark the field as reportable? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee921481.aspx for more information about this topic.

Comment: Reading/checking now but I think I love you

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ewald Hofman's link, I ran

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>witadmin listfields /collection:http://SomeServer/tfs > \tmp\witadmin.txt
```

and discovered a host of things not configured

> Reportable As: None

At this point, I punted the ticket to the TFS admins and indicated they needed to fix things. In particular, examine these two fields

```
  Field: Application.Changes
  Name: ApplicationChanges
  Type: PlainText
  Use: Project1, Project2
  Indexed: False
  Reportable As: None
```

or

```
  Field: Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ApplicationChanges
  Name: Application Changes
  Type: Html
  Use: Project1, Project2
  Indexed: False
  Reportable As: None
```

It will be a while before the TFS Admins do anything but I'm happy to accept Edwald's answer.